# When is a function between two topological vector spaces uniformly continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the definition of an uniformly continuous function from one topological vector space to another topological vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$, $Y$ be two topological vector spaces. A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous if for every neighborhood $V$ of $0\in Y$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $0\in X$ such that
$$
x-y\in U\implies f(x)-f(y)\in V.
$$